# How to remove a JSON node using Oracle's JSON functions

Tags: json, oracle

I have a JSON string like the following in a VARCHAR2 column in an Oracle database.

```
{
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": "20",
  "extras": {
    "address": "123 Main St"
  }
}
```

I want to remove the "extras" node from the JSON string and return the result, like:

```
{
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": "20"
}
```

I already know how to parse out pieces of a JSON string using Oracle JSON functions like [json_value, json_table, json_query](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6246). Unfortunately, I am stuck on Oracle 12.1 so I cannot use functions like [json_object, json_aggobject](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADJSN/generation.htm#ADJSN-GUID-6C3441E8-4F02-4E95-969C-BBCA6BDBBD9A), which were added in 12.2.

I tried using a path syntax like `json_query(data, '$["name"]["age"]')` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27820394/539048)) but it appears Oracle doesn't support that kind of path syntax.

I could solve this by explicitly extracting each of the known keys from the original object and recombining using concatenation, like:

```
select '{"name":"' || json_value(data,'$.name') 
     ||'","age":"' || json_value(data,'$.age') || '"}' result
from (
    select '{"name":"Bob","age":"20","extras":{"address":"123 Main St"}}' data
    from dual);
```

But I want to do this generically so that I don't have the keys hard-coded into the SQL expression (I expect that other keys might be added in the future).

**How can I just remove the "extras" node without hard-coding a list of keys in my SQL statement?**

Answer (score 1):

In oracle 12.2 the are new calls you can do to remove it. In the steps below I build your string, output it, remove the "extras" and output it again:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  l_obj JSON_OBJECT_T;
BEGIN
  -- New empty object using constructor.
  -- With or without the NEW keyword.
  l_obj := JSON_OBJECT_T();
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('l_obj.stringify = ' || l_obj.stringify);
  l_obj := NEW JSON_OBJECT_T();
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('l_obj.stringify = ' || l_obj.stringify);

 -- New object based on some JSON text using constructor.
 -- With or without the NEW keyword.
  l_obj := JSON_OBJECT_T('{
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": "20",
  "extras": {
  "address": "123 Main St"
  }
}');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('l_obj.stringify = ' || l_obj.stringify);

  -- remove "extras"
  l_obj.remove('extras');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('l_obj.stringify = ' || l_obj.stringify);
END;
/
```