# JSONPath exclude key in paths

Tags: jsonpath

Given a json like this:

```
{
"post": {
        "operationId": "post-collection",
        "responses": {
          "201": {
            "description": "Post something",
            "content": {
              "application/ld+json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "./models/Mapping.jsonld.json"
                }
              },
              "application/hal+json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "./models/Mapping.jsonHal.json"
                }
              },
              "application/vnd.api+json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "./models/Mapping.vndApi.json"                },
                ...
         }
     }
}
```

I want the content for all, BUT `application/ld+json`
I found a thread on how to do this based on the value: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29710922/1092632 but how would I exclude a key?

Basically what I am asking is the negative of this: `$..content[application/ld+json]`

Is this possible without any functions / programming? I used this for testing: https://jsonpath.com/

Answer (score 1):

https://jsonpath.com/ uses [JSONPath Plus](https://jsonpath-plus.github.io/JSONPath/docs/ts/#jsonpath-plus-)

It provides `@property` shorthand selector within filters

```
$..content[?(@property != 'application/ld+json')]
```

[image: JSONPath test screenshot]